# Is it possible to use onmouseover on a whole column in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip2

I am using a tooltip plugin called qTip2.

I would like to be able to show a tooltip, when a user puts the mouse over a column in my table. So it doesnt matter which row in the column the user choses, and the tooltip should not turn off while switching rows.

Is it possible to accomplish this?

qTip2 works with classes, so i would have to give each row in the column the same class name and tooltip-text for it to work. And it would turn on and off while switching between rows in the same column.

So what i would like to know is, if there is a global way to mark a whole column in a table with one class?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simply applying a class to the td? For example, <td class="className">

Comment: @AlexMorales have you tried reading the question? _so i would have to give each row in the column the same class name_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you could do this after the table is built...

```
$("#tableID tr td:nth-child(n)").addClass("column-class");
```

Change the tableID, the (n) in nth-child to the column number (1 based, not 0) and change column-class to the class name you want to add.

You could alternatively handle the mouseover and mouseleave events with the same code, rather than adding the class, but it sounds easier to use the class name if you've already got a plugin doing other things.

Answer (score -1):

I take it applying the class to the `<tr>` doesn't work, and neither does specifying a CSS selector like `TR.myClass TD`?

In which case, you'll have to either apply the class to each `<td>` or use a better plugin.